# NoSQL big data implementation/saving

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Lets say I have the following entities:

```
Student (Name, Courses, Department, Grades, Age, Gender, Address, Schedule)
Course (Name,  Schedule, MaxStudent, EligibleStudents, Department, PreRequisite, CoRequisite)
Department (Name, NumberOfStudents)
Grades (Course, Value)
```

These are linked data. How should I save them in NoSQL?
I heard that joins are not encourage in NOSQL...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ask about MongoDB there are to ways of modeling relationships between entities - [embedding](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/#embedded-data_http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/#embedded-data) and [linking/referencing](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/).

Generally speaking which one you choose depends on access patterns, atomicity considerations, expected document size growth and so on. There is no such thing like MongoDB equivalent of n-th normal form.

There is pretty extensive documentation on [docs.mongodb.org](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/) so it is a good place to start.

- [Data Modeling Introduction](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/)
- [Data Modeling Concepts](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-models/)
- [Data Model Examples and Patterns](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/data-models/)

You can also watch short video about [MongoDB schema design](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ufiFaY995GQ) by Dwight Merriman.

Note: Please don't use terms NoSQL and Big Data here. They are just the buzzwords and are almost completely meaningless when you ask programming related question.